# How can I run an entire FinalBuilder script remotely?

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-access, finalbuilder

I would like to be able to write a FinalBuilder script from my laptop where all commands are being run on a VM remotely. I need more than just PsExec. For example, I want to be able to change a registry key on the VM while running the FinalBuilder script from my laptop.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need FinalBuilder installed on the vm to be able to do this, and copy the script to the VM. The you would have a 'controller' script on your laptop that uses psexec to to run fbcmd.exe on the vm with the script. You would need a separate license for the vm as you cannot use the same license on 2 machines at the same time (unless you have multiple floating licenses).